# C function pointer and struct

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I am new to C function pointer and structure. Here is what I want to achieve say there is a structure

`typedef struct gfcrequest_t gfcrequest_t;`

Later on this struct will be used to point to a function and the function will be called

```c
gfcrequest_t *gfc_create();
gfr = gfc_create();
gfc_set_server(&gfr, server);
gfc_set_port(&gfr, port);
```

So are the following codes correct to initiate and later on I could add elements like server name and port number?

```c
gfcrequest_t *gfc_create() {
  struct out {
    struct hostent *server; 
    int portno;
    };
  return out;
}

void gfc_set_port(gfcrequest_t **gfr, unsigned short port) {
    gfr.portno = port;
}

void gfc_set_server(gfcrequest_t **gfr, const char *server) {
    gfr.server = gethostbyname(server);
}
```

Comment: "*are the following codes correct*". If you attempt to compile it you will be able to answer that as no it is not correct as it is not even valid syntax. Also your use of "function pointer" is confusing. There is no function pointers involved and "struct will be used to point to a function" doesn't make sense as a struct can't point to anything. Are you just trying to create a struct and return it from the function? If so you need to define the struct outside the function and use `malloc` to create a new struct to be returned.

Comment: user2236600, rather than ask us to do what a compiler can rapidly tell you, try a compiler first.

Comment: `.` is used to access a struct. `->` is required to access a  pointer to a struct. Also, the functions should take `gfcrequest_t *` not `gfcrequest_t **`. These errors clearly show you have not understood fundamentals of the language. Suggest you pause coding and systematically review a good C book or tutorial.

Comment: @user2236600 How is the structure out related to the structure gfcrequest_t or its pointer?

Comment: @user2236600 This declaration gfcrequest_t *gfc_create(); does not declare a function pointer. It declares a function that returns a pointer to an object of the type gfcrequest_t.

Answer (score 0):

thats not how you do pointers to function.
to declare a pointer to function you do this:

if your function is:

```
int ft_somefink (int a, int b);
```

the pointer should be:

```
struct                                  s_structure;
typedef struct s_structure              t_structure;    

struct s_structure
{
    int (*funct)(int, int);
};
```

the typedef is there to simplify syntax.
its just an alias to avoid having to type "struct" everytime you use the structure.

you initialize it like so:

```
int main ()
{
    t_structure name;

    name.funct = &ft_somefink;
    
}
```

And call it like so:

```
int main()
{
    t_structure name;
    int a;
    int b;

    a = 1;
    b = 2;

    name.funct = &ft_somefink;

    ...
    
    name.funct(a, b);
    
}
```

or like so if you pass the structure as pointer, it should look like this:
the main:

```
int main ()
{
    t_structure *name;
        
    ...
    function_somthing_useful(&name);
 
}

and the function:


void function_something_useful(t_structure **name)
{
    if (!(*name = malloc(sizeof(t_structure))))
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "malloc error, not enough memory or swap nvm\n")
        return ;
    }


    name->funct = &ft_somefink;

}
```

And, obviously, you call it then by:

```
   name->funct(a, b);
```

note that you can malloc in main, doesnt matter. the idea to pass just the pointer is to avoid having to copy the whole structure everytime you pass it to a function.

the difference between . and -> operator is a dereferencing, but that would be another subject.
also i think it is better to pass the function as a pointer, instead of the whole thing because that might imply copying all of the functions instructions. not 100% sure of that tho... or rather depends on the system.
on linux reads are suposed to be "atomic", which, in my experience includes what happens on the stack. couldnt speak about other systems tho...
definitely could use someone to fill in the blanks here...